# In React, how do I change the classname of one element that was created in an iteration, onclick of another element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a class to ONE specific element. The user clicks a remove button, then the entire row containing the button in a table should appear disabled after a class "removed" is added to the containing row div.
There are multiple rows created using array.map.
I tried this: [How to access/override the className of an element using refs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57781912/how-to-access-override-the-classname-of-an-element-using-refs)
But useRef targets only the last version of the div created in the iteration, useState for conditional className changes all iterations of that div.

```
const AccordionBody = ({...props }) => {
  
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  //data is loaded from api
  // set state 
  ...
  const handleRemove = (id) => {
    // ... sending remove ID to api 
    // add class "removed" to grandparent of button
  };

  return (
   {data.list.map((item) => (
          // change this parent div. Tried useRef and conditional className here.
          <div className={`c-table__row`} key={item.id} >
            <div className="c-table__row__item">
              // this is the button triggering the change
              <div className="e-btn__x" onClick={(e) => handleRemove(item.id)}></div>
              <img className="u-img--round" src={item.icon}/>
              <span className="c-table__cell">
                {item.name}
              </span>
            </div>
            <div className="c-table__row__item ">
                {item.location}
            </div>
            //more info in this row
            ...
          </div>
        ))}
}
```

Comment: How about adding a specific (boolean) property on that item in the state? And what should happen if API call fails for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the status of whether a row is disabled or not into the `data.list` array in state. Probably something like:

```
{data.list.map((item, i) => (
  // ...
  onClick={(e) => handleRemove(i)
```

```
const handleRemove = (index) => {
  setData({
    ...data,
    list: [
      ...data.list.slice(0, index),
      { ...data.list[index], disabled: true },
      ...data.list.slice(index + 1),
    ]
  });
};
```

Then, when rendering, use the `disabled` property to give the row a class name.

```
<div
    className={`c-table__row${item.disabled ? ' disabled' : ''}`}
    key={item.id}
>
```

Comment: Thanks certainperformance and @raina77ow, that way works. I guess I was thinking there must be some advanced way to implement useRef that I didn't know.

Comment: There is, but putting the status into state is the more react-way of doing things.

Comment: Makes sense, and seems obvious now. Honestly modifying data in state didn't that way didn't even occur to me, and I forgot about the index param in array.map.